# Excel formulas are deleting without knowing the reason

Tags: excel

I have an excel workbook, in one of the sheet we have sumiff formulas in 13 columns. these formulas are placed up to 15000 rows.

=SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,A3,B:B,RIGHT($N$1,10))

all the formulas are deleting automatically some times, how to trace this or what is the cause of deleting all the formulas in 13 columns.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of VBA you may find the cause.
Press Alt+F11 to bring the VBA editor.
Double click on the `ThisWorkbook` module of the Workbook having problems in left-top panel to edit it.

Add the following code (adapted from [here](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?504565-Excel-Cell-Deleted-event))

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim del As Boolean
    del = False
    For Each aCell In Target.Cells              ' Target may contain more than one cells.
        'If aCell.Formula = "" Then              ' Option #1
        If Len(Trim(aCell.Value)) = 0 Then      ' Option #2
            'MsgBox "Cell " & aCell.Address & " in sheet " & Sh.Name & " has been cleared or deleted."         ' Uncomment this line for further diagnostics
            del = True
        'Else                                    ' Uncomment these two lines for further diagnostics
        '   MsgBox "Cell " & aCell.Address & " in sheet " & Sh.Name & " has been changed."
        End If
        If (del) Then Exit For
    Next
    MsgBox "At least on cell in range " & Target.Address & " in sheet " & Sh.Name & " has been cleared or deleted."

End Sub
```

Options #1 or #2 should work equally well.
You may uncomment some of the lines for further diagnostics.
It may become too verbose, and I expect it not be necessary.

You will need to save the workbook as `.xlsm`.